# Five classes of ultrafilters on $\mathbb{R}$ (terminology)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, terminology, filters

It is obvious that an ultrafilter on $\mathbb{R}$ is one of the following:

- a trivial (principal) ultrafilter;
- lies in a finite right neighborhood of a real number;
- lies in a finite left neighborhood of a real number;
- lies in the neighborhood of positive infinity;
- lies in the neighborhood of negative infinity.

The name of the first class is "trivial" or "principal".

Are there well-established names for the rest four classes of ultrafilters?

I could call them:

- ultrafilter at the right of a real number;
- ultrafilter at the left of a real number;
- ultrafilter at positive infinity;
- ultrafilter at negative infinity.

But these terms are just my own words. Is there a well-established terminology for these four classes?

Comment: What do you mean by that the ultrafilter "lies in a finite right neighbourhood of a real number", which I suppose means some $[x,x+r)$ ? Members of the ultrafilter are typically a lot larger than sets like that.. Ditto for the other terms besides principal ultrafilter (which is a standard term). I have no clue what you mean.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I mean that the set $(x,x+r)$ (not $[x,x+r)$) is a member of our filter. Maybe my terminology was unfortunate: I say: a filter lies in a set iff the set is a member of the filter

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Correction: I mean that the set $(x,x+r)$ is a member of our ultrafilter for *every* $r>0$